# Passing object prototype function call into input keypress detection event handler

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to pass an object prototype function call within an input keypress detection event handler but am not sure how to go about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The code is given below :

```
function foo{};

foo.prototype.shout = function() {
  alert(shout);
}

foo.prototype.someOtherFunction = function (event) {
  var e = event || window.event,
      code = e.charCode || e.keyCode;

    if(code === 38) {
       foo.shout// This is what doesn't work - sorry for the confusion
    }
}

foo.prototype.applyKeypress = function (_input) {
  var self = this;
      _input.onkeypress = foo.someOtherFunction; // someOtherFunction applied here
}
```

Comment: Your first source for helpful information would be your browser's console.

Comment: Objects don't inherit from their own public prototype but from their constructor's prototype. It's referred to as the object's private `[[Prototype]]` property.

Comment: Also, I suspect `code` should be `e.keyCode` or `e.which`.

Comment: Remove the `prototype`, `foo.shout = function`, `foo.someOtherFunction = function`

Answer (score 2):

As stated seconds before my post - you didn't create the object

http://jsfiddle.net/Smzuu/2/

I changed your code a little so it would run. Small things you missed out when writing this example code, I hope

```
function foo(){};

foo.prototype.shout = function() {
  alert("hello"); //alert(shout); // shout was not defined.
}

var sampleInput = document.getElementById('sampleInputField');

sampleInput.onkeypress = function(e) {
    if(e.charCode === 97) { // A pressed
      new foo().shout(); 
    }
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't work because you haven't created an object:

```
function foo(){};

foo.prototype.shout = function() {
  alert(shout);
}

var o = new foo();

var sampleInput = document.getElementById('sampleInputField');

sampleInput.onkeypress = function(e) {
  if(code === 38) { //up arrow press
    o.shout() //now it works because it's an object, not a constructor
  }
}
```

Comment: Also need a `shout` variable, or some quotes around it.

Comment: Thanks - very helpful. But what if you wanted to make the shout function accessible to any object that inherits from the parent instead of creating a new object then applying it?

Comment: @neitony: I'm not sure I can understand what "what if you wanted to make the shout function accessible to any object that inherits from the parent instead of creating a new object then applying it" means. You have declared `foo` class with one method `shout()` - so you can create any amount of objects you want now.

Comment: Ok, so using your example, in order to use the shout function I had to create an instance of the object right? But what if I wanted to make it such that the shout method is already available when the object is created - I have adjusted the code sample above to give you a better idea. Thanks for your help

Comment: @neitony: the shout method is already available when the object is created - that is